# A test question, complete the sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, exam-questions

> Q: According to recent studies, bananas are the most promising food for an edible vaccine against the hepatitis B virus,
>
> A) but this virus is very common in many African countries
>
> B) so that potatoes, tomatoes and other vegetables  might serve to immunize people some day
>
> C) just as symptoms of acute viral hepatitis usually begin  suddenly
>
> D) which lives in about 5 per cent of the world's population
>
> E) whereas scientists have discovered a way to boost the level of immune-triggering hepatitis protein in the fruit

This is the question. I am asked to complete the sentence. The given answer is E. I think the answer should be D.

This is what I think about the question:

D seems to  be the correct answer because it explains Hepatitis B virus. E, however should be wrong because "whereas" doesn't really go well with the rest of the sentence. Can you explain if I am wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, Pufu. [whereas](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whereas) is used to contrast two disparate pieces of information:

> bananas are yellow whereas dates are brown

Example E is not disparate information, indeed it offers a reason for the first part, and so it should begin with [because](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/because).

Example D provides additional information about the first part, and so it is appropriate to start the clause with the relative pronoun [which](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/which).

Comment: Agreed, this is not a very well-written question.  (E) is the answer I would *expect* from context  (why *bananas*?), but the *whereas* throws me off. Of the remaining choices, (D) is the only one that fits, even if it leaves the sentence feeling incomplete

Comment: @Andrew: Why bananas? Apparently because it's easy to grow in countries where HepB is a problem. https://www.theguardian.com/science/2000/sep/08/gm.infectiousdiseases

Comment: I mean that the most curious thing about the sentence is that they're putting the vaccine in bananas. I wanted to know how that worked, which (E) answers.  (D) just gives me related but ancillary information.

Comment: "whereas" seems to be used in the sort of legalese sense here.

Comment: @MarkS. There are two legalese meanings. The first matches the general meaning: the second has to be used at the beginning of a recital or formal document. http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Whereas. So even the legalese sense doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

like other friends I believe that "D" is correct in every sence of the world!! which is conecting 2 independant clauses and is explaining hepatitis B.
whereas is used to show contrast while there isn't any contrasts!